# Conditional populate with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm facing a problem with `Mongoose`. I have multiple models:

- Transaction
- Wallet
- User
- Organization

I'm trying to fetch Transactions.

Each Transaction contains a `senderWalletId` and a `receiverWalletId` that have a `reference` to `Wallet`.

Wallets have a field called `type` that can be either `Organization` or `User` and a field called `owner` that contains a reference to either a `User` or an `Organization`. I achieved this through a ref path to the `type` property value of the same wallet, like this.

```
type: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      'User',
      'Organization',
      'Moneypot',
    ],
  },
  owner: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    refPath: "type"
  }
```

Now, I want to populate the `owner` of `receiverWalletId` and `senderWalletId`. If the type is `Organization`, I want to retrieve the `name`, `phoneNumber`, and `email`. If the type is `User`, I want to retrieve `firstName`, `lastNmae`, `email`, and `phoneNumber`.
I partially achieved this through this code:

```
.populate({
      path: 'senderWalletId',
      select: ['owner', 'type'],
      match: { type: { $eq: 'User' } },
      populate: {
        path: 'owner',
        select: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'phoneNumber', 'email']
      }
    })
    .populate({
      path: 'receiverWalletId',
      select: ['owner', 'type'],
      match: { type: { $eq: 'User' } },
      populate: {
        path: 'owner',
        select: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'phoneNumber', 'email']
      }
    })
```

Now the question is, how to make these populations retrieve  `name` instead of `firstName` and `lastName` when the type equal to an `organization`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this by putting all the properties inside the select array, like this:

```
   .populate({
      path: 'senderWalletId',
      select: ['owner', 'type'],
      match: { type: { $eq: 'User' } },
      populate: {
        path: 'owner',
        select: ['name', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phoneNumber', 'email']
      }
    })
    .populate({
      path: 'receiverWalletId',
      select: ['owner', 'type'],
      match: { type: { $eq: 'User' } },
      populate: {
        path: 'owner',
        select: ['name', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phoneNumber', 'email']
      }
    })
```

The power of NoSQL comes to use now as the returned array contains `firstName` and `lastName` in case the wallet type is `User`, and it contains `name` for the case where it is an `organization`